# Importance of the Quotes

Tags: web-applications, sql-injection

I want to understand it in the two conditions are below:-

1. First in the sql syntax error ( right syntax to use near ''' at line 1). How do i break it. I know it show that we can talk to the database but **how it shows that the site is vulnerable?**
2. Second condition is in this-
   '1 or '1'='1 , 1' or '1'='1 . I know that the 1=1 always true but in the LHS there are close quotes and in the RHS there is only single quotes so **how it is true?**

Comment: Can you show us the code that generates these errors? It's hard to know what you talk about without seeing it.

Comment: I am talking about the sql code.